# PHP XML DOM extension

Tags: php, dom

I keep on seeing people use a property of the DOM extensions as such:

```
$node->tagName
```

yet I have not seen this property defined anywhere in the php manual yet it seems to work.

Any links to its definition would be helpful.

Comment: Which DOM extensions are you referring to?  There are a few in the standard PHP distribution?

Comment: the object was an instantiation of DOMDocument class which doesn't have that property as part of it's definition yet it works. The only DOM class that has that property is the DOMElement class. I just don't see how you can use another class' property that is not part of the class that you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`DOMElement` class](http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php) has a read-only public field called `tagName`.